# Adding table (dgrid/OnDemandGrid) under map using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am working with ArcGIS API for Javascript 4.9. I want to create a simple map view and display a table under it.

I am using this script as a base https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=highlight-features-by-geometry

Unlike this example, I don't need to select anything, just want to display table under the map showing all data from the layer and be able to edit this table.

My modified script is below. I don't know how to set 'data' variable to point it to the feature layer that I am using.

My script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Display Table</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #info,
    #gridDisplay {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 35%;
      background-color: white;
      border-color: grey;
      width: 100%;
      font-family: "Avenir Next W00", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #gridDisplay {
      z-index: 80;
    }

    #info {
      z-index: 90;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #info * {
      padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .info {
      line-height: 20px;
      padding-left: 5px ! important;
    }

    .dgrid-header,
    .dgrid-header-row {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #57585A;
    }

    .dgrid-row-even {
      background-color: #F7F8F8;
    }

    .dgrid-row-odd {
      background-color: #EFEFEF;
    }

    .dgrid-selected {
      background: #B4DAF5;
    }

    .dgrid-row {
      border: none
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/WebMap",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Legend",
        "esri/widgets/Expand",
        "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dstore/legacy/StoreAdapter",
        "dgrid/Selection"
      ],
      function(
        Map, WebMap, MapView, FeatureLayer,  
        Legend, Expand,
        OnDemandGrid, Memory, StoreAdapter, Selection
      ) {

        let map, view, fLayer, grid;
        
        const gridDiv = document.getElementById("grid");
        const infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");

        // create new map, view and flayer
        setupTheView();

        const gridFields = ["__OBJECTID", "WAL_NAME", "REGION", "WAL_ZONE", "REGION_WAL", "WAL_Value", "SWAL_Value" 
        ];
        
        let dataStore = new StoreAdapter({
          objectStore: new Memory({
            idProperty: "__OBJECTID" 
          })
        });

        var sortAttr = [{
              attribute: "name",
              descending: true
        }]; 
        
        grid = new OnDemandGrid({
          store: Memory({
          idProperty: "OBJECTID"
           }),
           columns: {
                  WAL_NAME: "WAL_NAME",
                  REGION: "REGION",
                  WAL_Value: "WAL_Value",
                  SWAL_Value: "SWAL_Value",
              },
              loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
              noDataMessage: "No results found.",
              sort: sortAttr
          }, "grid");
        
        // how to set up this data variable to point back to my feature layer??
        data = ????
        
        grid.store.setData(data);
        grid.refresh();

        function setupTheView() {
          map = new Map({
            basemap: "topo"
          });
          view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",  // Reference to the scene div created in step 5
            map: map,  // Reference to the map object created before the scene
            zoom: 5,  // Sets zoom level based on level of detail (LOD)
            center: [146, -25],  // Sets center point of view using longitude,latitude
            //popup: {dockEnabled: false}
          });

          fLayer = new FeatureLayer({
            url: "https://--------/arcgis/rest/services/GCX/QFESAlertLevels_GCX/FeatureServer/1",
            outFields: ["*"],
            title: "WAL"
            //popupTemplate: popupReport
          });
        
          map.layers.add(fLayer);
          
          const legendExpand = new Expand({
            view: view,
            content: new Legend({
              view: view,
              style: "card"
            })
          });
         
          view.ui.add(legendExpand, "top-left");

          view.popup.watch("visible", function(newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
              clearUpSelection();
            }
          });
       }
        function errorCallback(error) {
          console.log("error:", error)
       }
     });
 
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv">
    <div>title="Display Table"
      </div>
    <div id="info">
      <span class="info">
        <b>Table</b>
      </span>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div id="grid"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of objects, where each object contains the attributes for each feature in the layer:

```
data = [{
    field0 : value, //Feature 0
    field1: value
    },
    field0: value, //Feature 1
    field1: value
    }]
```

You can get the fields and features from a layer using `queryFeatures()`, where layer is layer variable:

```
var layer = new FeatureLayer({
    portalItem: {
      id: '87eefb4c13c242349af2cc2b7e4df19b'
    },
    title: 'Some Tile'
})

layer.queryFeatures()
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)

        //Map the fields to dgrid format.
        var QueryFields = array.map(response.fields, function (field) {
          return {
            field: field.name,
            label: field.alias
          }
        })

        var TableFeatures = []
        array.forEach(response.features, function (feature) {

            var TableAttributes = {}
            var TableFields = Object.keys(feature.attributes)

            for (var i = 0; i < TableFields.length; i++) {
                TableAttributes[TableFields[i]] = feature.attributes[TableFields[i]]
            }

            TableFeatures.push(TableAttributes)
        })         

    var DataStore = new Memory({
        data: TableFeatures,
        idProperty: "OBJECTID",
    })

    var grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, ColumnHider, ColumnResizer, 
    ColumnReorder]))({
        bufferRows: Infinity,
        selectionMode: 'extended',
        columns: QueryFields
    }, divID)

    grid.set('collection', DataStore)
```

Also, I believe `"dojo/store/Memory"` is now `"dstore/Memory"` and `OnDemandGrid` needs to be set with `grid.set('collection, yourStore)`.

[Here](https://github.com/mebuie/ESRI_FeatureTable_Widget_4_9) is the code to a Feature Table Widget I'm working on and [here](http://markbuie.com/projects/featuretablewidget/index.html) is an example of the working code.